# Invalid Session Token (Code: 209 Version: 1.7.4)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Every time I go to run my app the app runs fine but the console prints an error. The error is `"Invalid Session Token (Code: 209 Version: 1.7.4)"`

I checked Parse.com and they told me to handle this error, writing a global utility function that is called by all of my parse request error callbacks. They said i can handle the "invalid session token" error in this global function and I should prompt the user to login again so that they can obtain a new session token. However when I try to input the code in my app I get the error that I am using unresolved identifiers.

Does anyone know how to fix an Invalid Session Token error. Or how I can use the code "kPFErrorInvalidSessionToken" in my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (the language I am writing in is swift)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to call `ParseErrorHandler.handleParseError(err)` not just only from `AppDelegate`, but also from other view controllers and it was not worked properly. Here is solution which works from every VC:

```
class ParseErrorHandler {
    class func handleParseError(error: NSError) {

    if error.domain != PFParseErrorDomain {
        return
    }

    switch (error.code) {

        // error code 209 handling
    case PFErrorCode.ErrorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue:

        invalidSessionTokenHandler()

    default:
        break
    }
}

// NOTE: User has no other option but to log out in this implementation

private class func invalidSessionTokenHandler() {

    let message: String = "Session is no longer valid! Please login again!"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

    while (vc!.presentedViewController != nil)
    {
        vc = vc!.presentedViewController
    }

    vc?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
        (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let exampleViewController: SignUpViewController  = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
        vc?.presentViewController(exampleViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        PFUser.logOut()
    })

    alert.addAction(logoutAction)
}
}
```

Hopefully I will save somebody's time!

Answer (score 0):

If by saying "unresolved identifiers" you mean to "kPFErrorInvalidSessionToken" then you should use PFErrorCode.ErrorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue instead.
please tell me if you succeded in catching the error because all i get back is a nil NSErrorPointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, largely based on code in the Parse.com iOS developers guide.

```
class ParseErrorHandler {

    class func handleParseError(error: NSError) {

        if error.domain != PFParseErrorDomain {
            return
        }

        switch (error.code) {

        // error code 209 handling
        case PFErrorCode.ErrorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue:
            invalidSessionTokenHandler()

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // NOTE: User has no other option but to log out in this implementation
    private class func invalidSessionTokenHandler() {

        let message: String = "Session is no longer valid, you are no longer logged in"
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let presentingViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
        presentingViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
            (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let loginViewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:
            nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login_2.0")

            presentingViewController?.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            PFUser.logOut()
        })

        alert.addAction(logoutAction)
    }
}
```

Above is the errorHandler class that should be used to catch all errors according to the Parse documentation (in this case I'm only showing error 209)

Here is how I catch this error in AppDelegate.swift within application function:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: {
        (suceeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            ParseErrorHandler.handleParseError(err)
        }
    })
```

Note that the user is technically still logged in hence why logout is called